# Do Android apps force the use of SSL 3?

Tags: android, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslv3

In light of the recent POODLE vulnerability, the servers that I talk to in my Android app are disabling SSL 3.

The code where I make my HTTP requests looks something like this

```
AndroidHttpClient c = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("My Client/1.0");

try {
    SyncBasicHttpContext httpcontext = getHttpContext();
    HttpResponse jsonResponse = c.execute(request, httpcontext);
    Status status = jsonResponse.getStatus();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...etc
}
```

Is there anything I will need to do to my code to continue to be able to talk to the severs?